# Reduce results to first match for each pattern with spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql query, where I have to search for multiple identifiers:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE identifier IN ('abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'ghi')
```

Now I get hundreds of results for each of these matches, where I am only interested in the first match for each identifier, i.e. one row with `identifier == 'abc'`, one where `identifier == 'cde'` and so on.

What is the best way to reduce my result to only the first row for each match?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with SQL alone, or do you have access to the Spark Scala/Java/Python API as well?

Comment: SQL alone would be more convenient, at least

Comment: Are you using Databricks by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `first()` aggregation function (after grouping by `identifier`) to only get the first row in each group.
But I don't think you'll be able to select `*` with this approach. Instead, you can list every individual column you want to get:

```
SELECT identifier, first(col1), first(col2), first(col3), ...
    FROM my_table
    WHERE identifier IN ('abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'ghi')
    GROUP BY identifier
```

Another approach would be to fire a query for each identifier value with a limit of 1 and then `union all` the results.

With the DataFrame API, you can use your original query and then use `.dropDuplicates(["identifier"])` on the result to only keep a single row for each identifier value.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz ACK, thanks! (I upvoted your downvote explanation) :)

I'm not sure whether to edit my answer with your suggestions or delete it altogether (given that it was just off the top of my head and I definitely need to refresh my knowledge)

Comment: dropDuplicates seems like a good solution after a syntax fix

Answer (score 1):

The best approach certainly depends a bit on your data and also on what you mean by `first`. Is that any random row that happens to be returned first? Or first by some particular sort order?

A general flexible approach is using window functions. `row_number()` allows you to easily filter for the first row by window.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY ???) as row_num
  FROM my_table
  WHERE identifier IN ('abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'ghi')) tmp
WHERE
  row_num = 1
```

Though, aggregations like `first` or `max_by` are often more efficient. But these get quickly inconvenient when dealing with lots of columns.